# How to set main window of Eclipse RCP application to max size

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have to develop a simple Eclipse based application. I use Luna Eclipse RCP IDE(4.4). I would like are there declarative way to start my application with maximized size of main windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the `org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor`. You should find your `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` in the bundle where the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` is declared. The default name is `ApplicationNameWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` where `ApplicationName` is the name of your application. If you can not find it look your application class there is a `createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor()`.

```
@Override
public void postWindowCreate() {
    IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
    IWorkbenchWindow window = configurer.getWindow();
    window.getShell().setMaximized(true);
}
```

Comment: Something strange I could not add plugin org.eclipse.ui.application to dependency of my application. This plugin could not be found

Comment: I use Eclipse DSL Luna IDE.

Comment: org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications is an extension point not a bundle, you should find the declaration in the plugin.xml where your application class is stored.

Comment: I have found how this task can be resolved declarative. In file that describe application in my case this is Application.e4xmi in section where trimmed window is defined set tag "shellMaximized". Full path is Application->Trimmed Window->Supplementary->Tag